# Verify my work : Polar equation to Cartesian Equation

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

If we are given Polar equation $r = 2a\sin(\theta-\theta_{0})$
where $a,\theta_{0}$ are constants, we are asked to transform this equation to Cartesian equation.

My attempt :

$\sin(\theta-\theta_{0})=\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta_{0})-\sin(\theta_{0})\cos(\theta)$

$$r = 2a\sin(\theta-\theta_{0})$$
$$r = 2a(\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta_{0})-\sin(\theta_{0})\cos(\theta))$$
Now  performing the substitution we get : $$ x=r\cos(\theta) , y = r\sin(\theta) \implies \cos(\theta)=\frac{x}{r},\space \sin(\theta)= \frac{y}{r}$$

Plugging back we get :

$$ r = 2a(\frac{y}{r}\cos(\theta_{0})-\sin(\theta_{0})\frac{x}{r})$$
$$   r  = \frac{2a}{r}(y\cos(\theta_{0})-x\sin(\theta_{0}))/r$$
$$   r^{2} = 2a(y\cos(\theta_{0})-x\sin(\theta_{0})) $$
$$   x^{2}+y^{2} = 2ya\cos(\theta_{0})-2ax\sin(\theta_{0}) $$

$$   y^{2} - 2ya\cos(\theta_{0}) = -2ax\sin(\theta_{0}) -x^{2} $$

**Edit:**

After further manipulation suggested by  **J. W. Tanner** I arrived at a solution :

$$ (x+asin(\theta_{0}))^{2} + (y-acos(\theta_{0}))^2 = a^{2} $$

which of course is just a circle with a center of $C(-asin(\theta_{0}),acos(\theta_{0}))$ , and radius $ r = a $ .

Comment: Your computations are correct but your radius cannot depend on x or y. You have to complete the squares to identify the center and the radius.

Comment: Yes I did notice at last , and edited the original version

Comment: Next step:  $y^2-2ya \cos \theta_0 + (a \cos \theta_0)^2 + x^2 + 2ax \sin \theta_0 + (a \sin \theta_0)^2 = a^2 \cos^2 \theta_0 + a^2 \sin^2 \theta_0 = a^2$